# Combining the results of 3 tables with MAX(date)

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to combine 3 tables using sql joins while pulling the latest record from 2 of the tables using MAX(date).

I have tried several different queries using INNER JOINS and LEFT JOINS and have yet to come up with the expected result

```
SELECT clients.name, clients.company, latest_jobs.contractor, latest_jobs.job_type, latest_jobs.last_date, sales_calls.last_sales_date, sales_calls.client
FROM
 (SELECT
   contractor,
   MAX(start_date) AS last_date,
   job_type,
  FROM jobs
  GROUP BY contractor) AS latest_jobs
INNER JOIN clients ON latest_jobs.contractor = clients.name
(SELECT
   MAX(sales_date) AS last_sales_date,
   client,
  FROM sales_calls 
  GROUP BY client) AS latest_jobs
 LEFT JOIN sales_calls ON sales_calls.client = clients.name
ORDER BY clients.name
```

Clients Table

```
|-------------------| 
| name              | 
|-------------------|
| client 1          |        
|-------------------|
| client 2          |   
|-------------------|
| client 3          |         
|-------------------|
```

Jobs Table

```
|-------------------|---------|-------------| 
| job_type          | company | start_date  |
|-------------------|---------|-------------|
| job_type 1        |client 1 | 2019-02-01  |
|-------------------|---------|-------------|
| job_type 3        |client 2 | 2019-02-02  |
|-------------------|---------|-------------|
| job_type 2        |client 3 | 2019-02-03  |
|-------------------|---------|-------------| 
| job_type 4        |client 2 | 2019-02-05  |
|-------------------|---------|-------------|
| job_type 2        |client 1 | 2019-01-18  |
|-------------------|---------|-------------|
| job_type 3        |client 2 | 2019-01-15  |
|-------------------|---------|-------------|
| job_type 2        |client 3 | 2019-02-08  |
|-------------------|---------|-------------|
```

Sales Table

```
|---------|-------------| 
| company | sales_date  |
|---------|-------------|
|client 1 | 2019-02-01  |
|---------|-------------|
|client 2 | 2019-02-02  |
|---------|-------------|
|client 3 | 2019-02-03  |
|---------|-------------| 
| client 2 | 2019-02-05 |
|---------|-------------|
|client 1 | 2019-01-18  |
|---------|-------------|
|client 2 | 2019-01-15  |
|---------|-------------|
|client 3 | 2019-02-08  |
|-----------------------|
```

Expected Result

```
|----------|-----------------|-----------------|-----------------|
| Name     |  last_job_date  | last_job_type   | last_sales_date |
|----------|-----------------|-----------------|-----------------|
| client 1 |  2019-02-01     | job_type 1      |  2019-02-01     |
|----------|-----------------|-----------------|-----------------|
| client 2 |  2019-02-05     | job_type 4      |  2019-02-05     |
|----------|-----------------|-----------------|-----------------|
| client 3 |  2019-02-02     | job_type 3      |  2019-02-08     |
|----------|-----------------|-----------------|-----------------|
```

Comment: Hi. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The specification is not at all clear.  We see references to columns `name` and `company` in the clients table, and the example query referencing a column named `contracor` that we don't see defined. So our understanding of the relationships between the tables is a bit confuddled.

So we are just guessing.  But here's a guess at what we are trying to achieve.

```
SELECT c.name
     , c.company
     , j.contractor
     , j.job_type
     , j.start_date       AS last_job_date
     , s.last_sales_date
     , s.client
  FROM clients c

  LEFT
  JOIN ( SELECT ls.client
              , MAX(ls.sales_date) AS last_sales_date
           FROM sales_calls ls
          GROUP
             BY ls.client
       ) s
    ON s.client = c.name

  LEFT
  JOIN ( SELECT llj.company
              , MAX(llj.start_date) AS last_start_date
           FROM jobs llj
          GROUP
             BY llj.company
       ) lj
    ON lj.company = c.company

  LEFT
  JOIN jobs j
    ON j.company    = lj.company
   AND j.start_date = lj.last_start_date

 ORDER
    BY c.name
```

---

We are getting all the rows from `clients`, ordering them by `name`.

We use an inline view to get the latest sales_date for each client, and we join that result (as an outer join) to the rows from the clients table.

Similarly, we get the latest start_date from the jobs table for each company, in an inline view.  That result gets joined to the rows from the clients table.

We also join back to the jobs table to pick up values from columns on the row with the latest start_date. (If there are multiple rows for the same company and start_date, then this has a potential to return multiple rows, and there are some approaches to dealing with that.  For now, our query is assuming that the (company,start_date) tuple is unique.

Comment: this worked for me...I am going to edit to try and make it clearer as I see where it is confusing.  The naming conventions used are not the best on our database

Answer (score 0):

You can use this query, which `JOIN`s `client` to the latest job date and latest sales dates (generated using derived tables) and also to the `jobs` table to get the `job_type` for the last job:

```
SELECT c.name, 
       lj.last_job_date,
       j.job_type AS last_job_type,  
       ls.last_sales_date
FROM client c
JOIN jobs j ON j.company = c.name
JOIN (SELECT company, MAX(start_date) AS last_job_date
      FROM jobs
      GROUP BY company) lj ON lj.last_job_date = j.start_date AND lj.company = c.name
JOIN (SELECT company, MAX(sales_date) AS last_sales_date
      FROM sales
      GROUP BY company) ls ON ls.company = c.name
```

Output (note that based on your sample data your expected result is incorrect)

```
name        last_job_date   last_job_type   last_sales_date
client 1    2019-02-01      job_type 1      2019-02-01
client 2    2019-02-05      job_type 4      2019-02-05
client 3    2019-02-08      job_type 2      2019-02-08
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=249afa18858fc143992b0dbaa6d2b240)